# Codenameone how to search in list of containers?

Tags: codenameone

Ive created an arraylist of movies and using a loop I've given each movie a new containers so im displaying a list of containers with all the movies in my database, can I possible search for a single movie dynamically using something like onKeyreleased action in my search bar and refresh the list of containers to display the searched movie container..
Search is currently working for me using actionlistener, that's only triggered by pressing Enter, and the results I pass to a new form..

Answer (score 1):

Sure [Toolbar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) supports search mode. See this sample code that searches all the contacts on your phone. It's a bit old but should work, it's copied from the javadoc:

```java
Image duke = null;
try {
    duke = Image.createImage("/duke.png");
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
}
int fiveMM = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(5);
final Image finalDuke = duke.scaledWidth(fiveMM);
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
Form hi = new Form("Search", BoxLayout.y());
hi.add(new InfiniteProgress());
Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(()-> {
    // this will take a while...
    Contact[] cnts = Display.getInstance().getAllContacts(true, true, true, true, false, false);
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        hi.removeAll();
        for(Contact c : cnts) {
            MultiButton m = new MultiButton();
            m.setTextLine1(c.getDisplayName());
            m.setTextLine2(c.getPrimaryPhoneNumber());
            Image pic = c.getPhoto();
            if(pic != null) {
                m.setIcon(fill(pic, finalDuke.getWidth(), finalDuke.getHeight()));
            } else {
                m.setIcon(finalDuke);
            }
            hi.add(m);
        }
        hi.revalidate();
    });
});

hi.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> {
    String text = (String)e.getSource();
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        // clear search
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            cmp.setHidden(false);
            cmp.setVisible(true);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    } else {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            MultiButton mb = (MultiButton)cmp;
            String line1 = mb.getTextLine1();
            String line2 = mb.getTextLine2();
            boolean show = line1 != null && line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1 ||
                    line2 != null && line2.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
            mb.setHidden(!show);
            mb.setVisible(show);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    }
}, 4);

hi.show();
```

[image: Results of search]